# How to build HTML Documentation with Sandcastle

Tags: html, sandcastle, chm

How to build CHM / HTML Documentation with Sandcastle? Can build HTML file from XML or have to used .cs and dll files?

Answer (score 3):

> How to build CHM / HTML Documentation with Sandcastle?

Use the [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/).

> Can build HTML file from XML or have to used .cs and dll files?

I think it uses the `*.dll` and the `*.xml` (both together) as input. One of the 'tips' in the SHFB documentation says,

"When selecting either an assembly or an XML comments file, the help file builder will automatically add the partner file for you (i.e. the XML comments file for the like-named assembly or the assembly for the like-named comments file). Multiple files can also be selected and added in one go or dragged from Windows Explorer and dropped on the Documentation Sources node."

Answer (score 0):

Sandcastle uses dll to generate documentation. It also needs the xml from code comments to be build by visual studio. To do that, basically select output XML from your project build properties and then open the csproj (your VS project) in SandCastle Help file builder.